# set noemptypipe true in html2jade options, programmatic usage

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I'm using [html2jade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2jade) in its programmatic usage, and I want to set the noemptypipe option to true.

So far I have tried

```
html2jade.convertHtml(html, {
    noemptypipe: true
}, function(err, jade) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(jade);
});

html2jade.convertHtml(html, {
    noEmptyPipe: true
}, function(err, jade) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(jade);
});

html2jade.convertHtml(html, {
    writer: {
        noEmptyPipe: true
    }
}, function(err, jade) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(jade);
});

html2jade.convertHtml(html, {
    writer: {
        noemptypipe: true
    }
}, function(err, jade) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(jade);
});
```

but none of them work. I can't find any documentation on how to do this anywhere and I can't figure out what's going on in the
[code](https://github.com/donpark/html2jade/blob/master/lib/html2jade.coffee).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this one works fine,

```
html2jade.convertHtml(html, {
    noemptypipe: true
}, function(err, jade) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(jade);
});
```

I must have just been misspelling noemptypipe.